# mysqld[1108] [Warning] Aborted connection 7466 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, mariadb, warning

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04. It is a LEMP server running Mariadb. When I run the command `sudo service mariadb status` I get the following warnings:

```
Jul 28 00:18:59 mail.example.com mysqld[1108]: 2023-07-28  0:18:59 7466 [Warning] Aborted connection 7466 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Jul 28 00:18:59 mail.example.com mysqld[1108]: 2023-07-28  0:18:59 7467 [Warning] Aborted connection 7467 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Jul 28 00:18:59 mail.example.com mysqld[1108]: 2023-07-28  0:18:59 7469 [Warning] Aborted connection 7469 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Jul 28 00:18:59 mail.example.com mysqld[1108]: 2023-07-28  0:18:59 7470 [Warning] Aborted connection 7470 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Jul 28 00:18:59 mail.example.com mysqld[1108]: 2023-07-28  0:18:59 7471 [Warning] Aborted connection 7471 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Jul 28 00:18:59 mail.example.com mysqld[1108]: 2023-07-28  0:18:59 7472 [Warning] Aborted connection 7472 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Jul 28 00:18:59 mail.example.com mysqld[1108]: 2023-07-28  0:18:59 7474 [Warning] Aborted connection 7474 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Jul 28 00:18:59 mail.example.com mysqld[1108]: 2023-07-28  0:18:59 7475 [Warning] Aborted connection 7475 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

What does this warning mean and how can I debug and fix it?